# update the UI in React using render method

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, render

When I read react documentation, they said "[the only way to update the UI is to create a new element, and pass it to ReactDOM.render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element)". due to I have created code like this below.

```
function Clock() {
 // console.log('clock called'); 

  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
                  )

  return (
    element
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );

//every second call Clock
setInterval(Clock, 1000);
```

Every second the Clock component is called, so it creates a new element every second. when the Clock component passes to the render method. but the UI is not updated. why? I didn't call the render method every second. because the documentation isn't said: "call the render method every second". I thought when the new element is created, the render method will be called automatically. is my thought ok or not?

In the documentation the code like this below

```
function Clock(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Here they call the render method also every second. but in the documentation, They do not specify to call the render method for each update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve a dynamic updating for your components, you need to utilize state hooks, like `useEffect()` and `useState`.

```
//import { useState } from 'react';
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Clock() {

const time = new Date();
// a hook to maintain the state
 const [ state, setState] = useState();
// a listener to handle changes in the parameters of the array, in our case time
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(time.toLocaleTimeString());
  }, [time])
  
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {state}.</h2>
    </div>
                  )

  return (
    element
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

in the code posted, we use `useEffect()` hook to respond to any changes in the `Date()` object. Which was passed in the array after the callback function.

**What does this hook do?**

it calls `useState()` hook to update our state variable which I called `state`, which will be displayed accordingly whenever the time changes.

Comment: Your explanation is something new concept. but I'm not expected this. my problem is,  to change the UI shall we need to call ReactDOM.render() method again and again? or When we just create a new element, will be the render method automatically called to re-render the element by React?

Comment: no. any changes in the paramters array in `useEffect()` will trigger a re-render by itself. you do not need to call the render method more than once

Comment: If the useEffect() is not used,  I will need to recall the render method again and again to change the UI. is my thought correct or wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the render method should not be called more than once, you need to use the component state. you can use `setInterval` inside a function to update the state every second by creating a new date object instead of `useEffect`, but believe me using `useEffect` and `useState` will make your React development journey much easier.